# Python 2.7 - local vs global vars

Tags: python-2.7, global-variables, local-variables

So I am learning the difference between global and local vars in Python 2.7 and as per my understanding

**local var** is one that is defined within a function and 
**globar var** is one that is defined outside of the function.

I created this simple function to test how these local and global vars work when used in combination

```
def f():
    global s
    print s
    s = "Python is great."
    print s
```

Before I ran the function, I declared the global `s`

```
s = "I love python!" 
f()
```

The output was:

```
>>> f()
I love python
Python is great
```

I understand till this part, but what I don't understand is, when I call the run a `print s`  outside the function, why is it printing the local variable instead of the global one. Does this mean that the global var `s` is used once and discarded?

```
>>> print s
Python is great
```

can someone please explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... what I don't understand is, when I call the run a `print s` outside the function, why is it printing the local variable instead of the global one.

There is *no* local `s` within the function. The `global s` statement causes the Python VM to use the `s` in the global scope even when binding it.

Comment: So that means if I run a `print s` without declaring the global `s`, it will print the value of s as defined within the function, right? (since there is no global s defined?)

Comment: If you remove the `global s` statement within the function then calling the function will throw `UnboundLocalError` since the compiler will attempt to access the local `s` in the first line of the function (since you bound it within the function).

Answer (score 0):

You declared `s` to be a global in the function, *overriding* the default behaviour, by using the `global s` statement. Because `s` is now a global, and you assigned a new value to it, that change is visible globally.